# Git pushing local branch to remote branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-merge

I have two remote branches:

- master
- stable

The master branch is aligned to release; production ready code stays here.  The stable branch is used for testing. Our Hudson builder rebuilds the code on each push, to which I send the built product to the test team.

I also use local branches dependent to the stable branch for any given job.

I need to push commit to the stable branch to get build product, so after tests were passed, how can I merge local branch  - whose parent is the stable branch - to master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you finish your development on your `STABLE` branch you should merge it into master by go to command line:

`git checkout master` checkout to master branch.

`git pull` to make sure you have latest code.

`git merge stable` then when you editor pops up(if VI then hit :q) quit.

`git push -u origin master` to push the merged master to origin master.

thats it you have the latest code on master.

Comment: but i just want to merge related local branch (i.e bugfix_1234 )to master. you pushed all changes on stable to master.

Answer (score 0):

You run the risk of keeping your repositories out of date or invalid, but the solution you would want is:

- `git checkout master`
- `git pull`
- `git merge bugfix_1234`
- `git push origin master`

Take extreme care to ensure that `master` is merged back down with `stable` after doing something like this.